# Why does Signal is not availlable for installation on Samsung Tablet

Tags: applications, installation, instant-messaging

I want to install Signal on a Samsumg Galaxy Tab A (2016) with Android-Version 8.1.
According to Signal official page, Android 4.4 or superior is required (so, this should be no problem)
But in the Google Play app on the tablet, I can't find it.
And on the website ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.thoughtcrime.securesms ) , it clearly shows that Signal is NOT 2 of my tablets (the Tab A above, and a even younger one)

[image: Signal not availlable on 2 tablets]

( x sign to show the Signal app is not availlable on this device, and the "v" sign for availlable)

I have 2 ideas to explain this fact:

- I installed Google Family Link on these tablets. But as Signal is not age limited, I really don't understand
- these tablets has no SIM card slot. They are "WIFI version only".

Could someone help me installing Signal on this Tab A ?

Comment: https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/issues/10432

Comment: https://signal.org/android/apk download the Signal APK directly

Comment: Signal is only available for devices with built-in cellular functionality. But you can install and activate it manually. Note that for people using Signal as default SMS app it will get bit more complicated to send you an SMS instead of an Signal message as by default Signal prefers a Signal message instead of an SMS if the recipient is activated in Signal.

Comment: @Robert But Signal is installable on my laptop and desktop computers, which don't have cell phone connection.

Comment: Here is a good related feature request for me to track. https://community.signalusers.org/t/allow-android-ios-devices-e-g-tablets-but-also-phones-to-be-linked-to-the-primary-device-i-e-used-as-secondary-device-like-the-desktop-app/2884/223